# Spring Base Interceptor: Get Controller & Method Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create an interceptor that will make the current controller name and action (method) name available to my view. This seems to work great most of the time.

```
public class BaseInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        String controllerName = "";
        String actionName = "";

        if( handler instanceof HandlerMethod ) {
            // there are cases where this handler isn't an instance of HandlerMethod, so the cast fails.
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            controllerName = handlerMethod.getBean().getClass().getSimpleName().replace("Controller", "");
            actionName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getName();
        }

        modelAndView.addObject("controllerName", controllerName );
        modelAndView.addObject("actionName", actionName );
    }

}
```

The only time this doesn't work is when I am logged in using Spring Security. When this happens I get a the proxy wrapper as the controller name. Is there any way to get the actual controller name?

> Post$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ef51261

Answer (score 5):

This works for getting the controller name if you're using spring security or not.

controllerName  = handlerMethod.getBeanType().getSimpleName().replace("Controller", "");

Comment: Is there any way to get it from the HttpServletRequest ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but may be you can get the information from RequestMappingHandlerMapping . Just autowire RequestMappingHandlerMapping  in your interceptor and call getHandler method

Comment: idk.. this method is doing exactly what I want it to do 99% of the time. I think I am just missing something here.